# order of elements in direct product of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have $Zp^k\times ... \times Zp^k$, $m$ times. I want to find the number of elements having certain order in this group. I think the elements of order minor or equal to $p^s$ are $(s+1)^m$ so the elements of order precisely $p^s$ are $(s+1)^m - s^m$. Is that correct?

Edit: i was clearly wrong, confounding additive and multiplicative notation about groups. So the elements of order less or equal to $p^s$ are $p^{sm}$ because they are the $n$ in $Zp^k$ that satisfy $np^s=mp^k=0$ for some $m$ in the natural numbers. And so the elements of order precisely $p^s$ are $p^{sm}-p^{(s-1)m}$.

Comment: Are you guessing or do you have a proof for your claim?

Comment: This is clearly wrong, as it does not depend on $p$.. (Whereas the answer clearly should!) Try to look at some small examples to build your intuition.

Comment: I don't really get it. I mean my reasoning was, there are s+1 elements of order minor or equal to $p^s$ in $Zp^k$, namely $0, p, ..., p^s$ the others don't divide $p^k$ so are generators or have greater periods. So in the product i have m choiches and so $(s+1)^m$ are the elements with period minor or equal to $p^s$ i don't see why/where this is wrong.

Comment: What about $2p$?

Comment: Oh i was clearly confounding multiplicative/additive notation. I think i have get it, i'll edit my question.